# How to skip Junit for some java classes using mavan?

Tags: java, maven, junit, code-coverage

I have some classes for which I dont have to write junit classes so I want to skip Junit for some Java classes and want to increase Junit code coverage using Maven. For example, I have placed all Java classes in com.test.xxx package so that I can tell them all classes are to be skipped.

Comment: `@Ignore` or `@Disabled`?

Comment: @QBrute In this way it skip the test cases get running. It not increase the code coverage as far I know.

Comment: Are you sing something like sonar?

Comment: yes, I am using sonar

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@Disabled` Tag to disable a specific Test. If you just have empty  test classes, for whatever reason. Delete them.

If you want to fake code coverage for whatever reason, you can create tests and call your services inside the tests, but do not add any assertations... However this is extremly bad practice and I cant really suggest it to you.

Comment: Do you want to place @ Disabled in actual java classes ? I thought @ Disabled will go into test classes. can you please clarify ?